# ec2 api on openstack

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, openssl, cloud, openstack

I'm trying to install EC2_API on openstack ( newton ) 
I've got this problem ?
now the cloud is down : the problem is in every log

```
Please enter the password for the 'root' MySQL user:
Verified connectivity to MySQL.
Creating 'ec2api' database.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pip.exceptions import InstallationError, CommandError, PipError
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/exceptions.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.six import iteritems
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 64, in <module>
    vendored("cachecontrol")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 36, in vendored
    __import__(modulename, globals(), locals(), level=0)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/wrapper.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 54, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import rand, crypto, SSL
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 112, in <module>
    SSL_ST_INIT = _lib.SSL_ST_INIT
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SSL_ST_INIT'
```

Comment: curious why you are installing the EC2_API on OpenStack? Is there a tutorial you are trying to follow? Also, try first `pip uninstall pyOpenSSL` and then, `pip install pyOpenSSL`. After that, ```Now go to
....XXXX/w3af/w3af/core/controllers/dependency_check/requirements.py
and edit the python file
on line 39 is write:
PIPDependency('OpenSSL', 'pyOpenSSL', '0.15.1'),
Modify it to
PIPDependency('OpenSSL', 'pyOpenSSL', '16.2.0'),
OR
PIPDependency('OpenSSL', 'pyOpenSSL', 'Version of pyOpenSSL you are using'),```

Comment: @Lucas , thank you for your reply, to answer your question it's also or curiosity I'm installing EC2 API , 
i'm getting exactly the same problem when trying to run "pip uninstall pyOpenSSL"